# Play! 2 WS library : Detect and Handle Closed Connection in Streaming HTTP response

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

In the play WS library, I am using this call to process a streaming http response:

```
 def get[A](consumer: ResponseHeaders => Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]):
     Future[Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]]
```

I am passing it something like: `_ => (Iteratee.foreach(chunk => println(chunk)))`

Everything works fine, but at some point the connection seems to close and I don't know how to handle this.  I tried adding `.mapDone` to print out some stuff when the Iteratee is done, but it never happens.

On this get request, how can I detect that the connection has been closed and handle that event?

Comment: [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655566/file-writing-iteratee-does-not-receive-eof-for-ws-get) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not longer the problem in Play 2.2.3. Function passed to `map` as defined below should be invoked with `Unit` when the stream closes:

```
val connection = WS.url("http://example.com")
  .get(_ => iteratee).flatMap(_.run) map { _ => println("closed") }
```